# jBPM PROCESSINSTANCEINFO and WorkitemInfo tables in H2 db

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

I am new to jbpm and would like to know if the already configured H2 db stores the objects(DataItems) associated with the process and work item in it somewhere.

I can see there is a byte array present in both the tables and I am not sure what exactly that bytearray stores and how to unmarshall it.

Any sort of information would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *Info objects do store all relevant data the engine needs in a binary format.  This is not meant for query purposes however. If you want to get access to variable values, either use the audit logs or use pluggable variable persistence to store them separately (for example by making them a JPA entity they will be stored in a separate table).

Comment: Thanks Kris, Can you please provide more information on the second method(pluggable variable instance persistence to store them) , as I am not sure what exactly that means.